# Trying to use transform() function of CountVectorizer, without using fit()

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the CountVectorizer to vectorize an array of words from a corpus. One training set, and one set to test against. The training set is ok, and I use fit_transform(data) to train it. However I cant use fit() on the test set, but I am still supposed to vectorize it to use to check accuracy of predictions later. Therefore only calling  transform(). However when calling transform I get an error telling me the Vocabulary was not fitted.

I tried using _validate_vocabulary() however that does not fix the problem.

```
in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted      


  self.count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(lowercase=False,
                                            tokenizer=tokenize_my,
                                            max_features=5000)



    temp_vector = self.count_vectorizer
    temp_vector._validate_vocabulary()
    vec = temp_vector.transform(data)
    vec_tfidf = self.tfidf.transform(data)

    return vec, vec_tfidf
```

Never programmed in Python before, so maybe im missing something basic here, however cant figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Where do you fit your `CountVectorizer` on the training set ?

Comment: I have a class Vectorizer which has a train() and vectorize() function. The train() function runs fit_transform(). However I have been just running the .transform() not running any fit() commands prior. Should I be calling train() from vectorize() before using transform()?

Comment: Yes, you must train your vectorizer before using it. Usually, you want to fit your vectorizer on your training set. Then, with this trained version, you can transform both your training and your test sets.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, will do that then.